# Problem with rendering

Tags: rendering

I’m starting with blender and 3d modeling in general,I don’t know if this happens because my computer is not  really expensive,but when I try render a model,in this case I rendered a simple circle just to show you,the edges have this weird and horrible kind of distortion in the upper part,I would appreciate if someone helps me with this
Thanks
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwUfv.jpg

Comment: Hello and welcome! You can upload and embed images right into your question. This way readers will see everything at once and don't have to click here and there and then back again to return to the text. You can [edit your question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/227804/edit) any time. *hint! hint!*

Comment: Have you tried increasing sample counts?
Also is the denoising enabled?
Try enabling the denoising if disabled or increase the sample counts.

Comment: Nope, this has nothing to do with your computer, just with your settings in your blend file. Please upload your blend file by opening this https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow instructions, so we can help you.